# Is it possible to clear logs in SQL Server 2008 using a query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I noticed some suspicious activities on my database server. I inspect last 300 recent queries executed on my server using this T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(s2.objectid),'Ad-Hoc') AS ProcName,
        execution_count, s2.objectid,
        (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(s2.TEXT,statement_start_offset / 2+1 ,
           ( (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
                    THEN (LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),s2.TEXT)) * 2)
                    ELSE statement_end_offset 
              END)- statement_start_offset) / 2+1)) AS sql_statement,
    last_execution_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 ) x
WHERE 
    sql_statement NOT like 'SELECT TOP 50 * FROM(SELECT %'
--and OBJECTPROPERTYEX(x.objectid,'IsProcedure') = 1
ORDER BY 
    last_execution_time DESC
```

I believe yesterday someone delete logs from my server.

I want to know if this possible to delete recent queries logs with a query or remote access to database with SQL Server Management Studio. If possible, how ?

Comment: What kind of suspicious activity? There may be other things you can look at such as the default trace or event logs.

Answer (score 3):

`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` clears the procedure cache.

`sys.dm_exec_query_stats` only reports on queries in the cache. Restarting the machine or plans being flushed due to memory pressure or because they have been invalidated due to index or statistics maintenance are other possible reasons why the DMV would not contain older queries.