# How to clear error logs using query in SQL Server without restarting the instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to clear error logs using a query in SQL Server without restarting the server instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Safe way to truncate SQL Server Error Log](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31298/5203)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clear logs in SQL Server 2008 using a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893454/is-it-possible-to-clear-logs-in-sql-server-2008-using-a-query)

Comment: @AMAN77 No, that question is about query logs. This one is about error logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reference : [How to Recycle SQL Server Error Log file without restarting SQL Server Service](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/SQL-Server-Recycle-Error-Log-Without-Restarting-Service-DBCC-ErrorLog-or-SP_CYCLE_ERRORLOG/)

```
Use [master];
GO

SP_CYCLE_ERRORLOG
GO
```

Comment: This Is not Working without restart SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 6):

clear error logs using a query in SQL Server without restarting the server instance:

```
SP_CYCLE_ERRORLOG
```

After run the command, please check: "**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log**"
and delete old file (like: ERRORLOG.1, ERRORLOG.2 ...).
I open SQL port 1433, so my ERRORLOG about 20Gb. Some one scan my Sql password. Don't open port 1433 to internet.

Answer (score 4):

You can run: `sp_cycle_errorlog`

That will start a new log file.

If you want to really delete log entries, you'd have to run that command seven times. By default there are seven logs cycled through. But often DBAs change that to maximum possible of 99.

Comment: u are right, only after running it 7 times was the file really deleted, otherwise it just moves it to the next cycle